# How to fetch my custom XML file through a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jaxb, relative-path

I have a servlet which uses JAXB to unmarhsal and marshal an XML file, which I have made myself. My problem is that I can't unmarshal or marshal the XML file without giving the full local path to the XML file, the the marshaller. The problem with this, is that I can't deliver the project to my friend, without he need to edit the local path of the XML file. My code for the unmarshalling looks like this

```
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
CarList cl = factory.createCarList();

try {
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbCtx = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(cl.getClass().getPackage().getName());
    javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller();
    cl = (CarList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new java.io.File("/Users/martin/NetBeansProjects/Web-Mandatory-Assignment-Part1/web/resources/xml/Cars.xml")); //NOI18N
} catch (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("global").log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex); //NOI18N
}
```

As u can see I need to use '/Users/martin/NetBeansProjects/Web-Mandatory-Assignment-Part1/web/resources/xml/Cars.xml' as the path for the file, but what i want it to do, is to use somehting like 'xml/resources/Cars.xml' instead. How can I make this work :)

Comment: have you tried embedding the file as a resource of your app and load it with the classloader?

Comment: This is what @GuillaumePolet is talking about: `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)`

Comment: no, I haven't tried that. I will take a look at that method, and get back to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ServletContext` interface in `javax.servlet` package. For access to instance of this class use following code:

```
   http_request_instance.getServletContext();
```

There are useful methods in this interface such as:

- `getResource(String)`
- `getResourceAsStream(String)`
- `getRealPath(String)`

for more information see:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html
- http://www.javadocexamples.com/javax/servlet/ServletContext/getResourceAsStream%28String%20path%29.html (good sample)